# Why do I keep getting Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in error in this codes?

Tags: php

I keep getting this:

> Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line
> detected in line 4.

How can improve these codes? And it was working before.

```
if ($query_run) {
        #redirect user if data is inserted
        echo '<script> alert("KPI data Saved");</script>';
        header("Location:cornfirma.php?kpi=$kpi_id&quantity=$quantity&year_id=$year_id");
    }
    else{
        echo '<script> alert("KPI Not Saved");</script>';
        echo $query .mysqli_error($conn).   $kpi_id;
    }
```

Comment: You realise the `echo` before the `header` command will never be seen by anyone, yes? That's the whole point of redirecting, it tells the browser to ignore anything coming from the current response and go to the suggested page instead.

Comment: Anyway, the error is saying that the header contains a new line character, which is not allowed. I suggest checking whether any of those variables you're putting in the URL contain newlines by mistake.

Comment: I cannot figure out any lines here..

Comment: Well it's not lying to you. If you can't see anything, try taking out the variables one by one until this error stops. Then at least you'll narrow it down a bit.

Comment: I have got it thank you. There was a space in  year_id=$year_id